# Display three chart in one jsp using same servlet and different request parameter

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart

I have following code in my jsp

```
<div id="ReloadThis">
            <img alt=""
                src='<%=url+"/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=HOUR"%>'>

            <img alt=""
                src='<%=url+"/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=MONTH"%>'>

            <img alt=""
                src='<%=url+"/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=YEAR"%>'>
        </div>
```

But it call servlet only one time.
When i enter servlet URL direcly it work perfect for all.

Comment: Do you want to give link to view diff type of charts or want to display three diff image simultaneously

Comment: want to view different chart hourly month and year base

Answer (score 1):

I think the browser is **caching the** `<img>`. Try giving different url's for different operation and map all the url's to the same servlet.

The Url's should like:

- /chartDemo/servlet/YearChartServlet
- /chartDemo/servlet/MonthChartServlet
- /chartDemo/servlet/HourChartServlet

Comment: Something like `"/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=...&amp;CHARTID=${chartId}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
   <div id="ReloadThis">
    <img alt=""
        src='"<%=url%>" + "/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=HOUR"'/>

    <img alt=""
        src='"<%=url%>" + "/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=MONTH"'/>

    <img alt=""
        src='"<%=url%>" + "/chartDemo/servlet/ChartServlet?CHARTTYPE=YEAR"'/>
</div>
```